How does this "wrong" solution, which doesn't explicitly use conditional probability, lead to the correct answer?
AMC, Fall 2021, 10B, Problem 20:

In a particular game, each of 4 players rolls a standard 6-sided die.
The winner is the player who rolls the highest number. If there is a
tie for the highest roll, those involved in the tie will roll again
and this process will continue until one player wins. Hugo is one of
the players in this game. What is the probability that Hugo's first
roll was a 5 given that he won the game?


Solution 1 takes into account only the first round, and calculates the probability that its highest roll is a 5. This does not take into account the cases possible: single 5, double 5, etc. Hence, the remark that the solution is incorrect. Yet, is there some deeper reason/symmetry/structure in the question because of which this wrong solution leads to the same numerical answer $\dfrac{41}{144}$ as in Solution 2 (which uses Bayes Theorem to correctly arrive at the answer)?
Edit:
Based on David K's remark, and what I have been thinking, Solution 1 is correct (based on symmetry). If we were to rephrase the question so that it read "what is the probability that the winner rolled a 5", then solution 1 makes sense. Even if insist on identifying Hugo, the probabilities for Hugo are the same (symmetrical) as the probabilities for the other players, and solution 1 makes sense. However, I am not able to show how Solution 1 and 2 are connected (for example, how the symmetrical probabilities lead back to the same answer). And I think that my symmetry answer is a little "hand-wavy". A more precise answer would be really appreciated.

+1 to your posted question, because I regard the underlying question as interesting.  However, I also regard your posted question as defective.  For example, you did not show the explicit math, directly in your posted question, to establish the two claims that you made.  Also, you did not attempt to answer your own question by exploration, also showing the exploration directly in your posted question.  For example, what if Hugo rolled a 4 instead?  Further, what if you had a 7 sided die, and Hugo rolled a 6?

Solution 1 is not wrong. The remark is wrong.

I agree with @DavidK. The remark says that additional tiebreaks haven't been taken into account. But that doesn't matter. The only information we can glean about the first round, which is the one we're interested in, is that Hugo won or drew it. And that information is correctly used to solve the problem.

I think the question is less how Solution 1 got the right answer, and more how Solution 2 got the right answer.

What 's wrong with solution 2? Isn't it standard Bayes?

Solution 2 looks completely correct apart from saying "wins on the next round" instead of "wins eventually".

Solution 1 is correct. Hugo wins, having rolled a five in the first round, if and only if the following two events happen: $A$, the highest score in the first round was $5$; and $B$, Hugo wins. But $A$ and $B$ are independent, since if you know the four numbers rolled in the first round, but not who rolled which one, any given player has probability $1/4$ of winning by symmetry. So $\Pr(A\cap B\mid B)=\Pr(A)$.

Beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for.

This certainly shows the original “solution 1” gives the correct answer for good reason, not coincidence.  But it doesn’t quite show that “solution 1 is correct” in the sense of including an essentially solid justification of the solution: the justification is missing a key step, which this answer exactly fills in.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine That's the perfect description of Solution 1's correctness. The subtle difference between doing the right thing and justifying that the thing is indeed right is so often missed or neglected.



Problem 20
In a particular game, each of $4$ players rolls a standard $6{ }$-sided die. The winner is the player who rolls the highest number. If there is a tie for the highest roll, those involved in the tie will roll again and this process will continue until one player wins. Hugo is one of the players in this game. What is the probability that Hugo's first roll was a $5,$ given that he won the game?
Solution 1
Since we know that Hugo wins, we know that he rolled the highest number in the first round. So, the required probability is just the probability that the highest roll in the first round is $5.$



Here's a detailed expansion of Solution 1:
\begin{align}{}&P(\text{Hugo's first roll} = 5\mid \text{winner} = \text{Hugo})
\\={}&\frac{P(\text{Hugo's first roll} = 5,\; \text{winner} = \text{Hugo})}{P(\text{winner} = \text{Hugo})}
\\={}&\frac{P(\text{the winner's first roll} = 5,\; \text{winner} = \text{Hugo})}{P(\text{winner} = \text{Hugo})}
\\={}&\frac{P(\text{the winner's first roll} = 5)\times P(\text{winner} = \text{Hugo})}{P(\text{winner} = \text{Hugo})}
\\={}&P(\text{the winner's first roll} = 5)
\\={}&P(\text{the first round's highest roll} = 5)
\\={}&P(\text{the first round's highest roll} \le 5)
\\{}&-P(\text{the first round's highest roll} \le 4)
\\={}&\left(\frac56\right)^4-\left(\frac46\right)^4,
\end{align}
as required.
Note that the third equality is due to the independence of the winner's first roll being 5 and the winner being Hugo (since the probability of the former event is $5$ is unaltered by the knowlege of the latter event), whilst the fifth equality reflects Solution 1's stated observation. While Solution/Argument 1 is not invalid, omitting its key step and justification makes it arguably sketchy rather than pithy.
On an orthogonal note, it's worth noting that the similar-looking event pair the Hugo's first roll being 5 and the winner being Hugo are not independent (since any knowledge of the former happening increases the probability of the latter).

Alternatively, take an arbitrary player $p$ (it doesn't matter whether $p$ is identified); then, by symmetry,
\begin{align}
{}&P(\text{Hugo's first roll} = 5\mid \text{winner} = \text{Hugo})
\\={}&P(p\text{'s first roll} = 5\mid \text{winner} = p)
\\={}&P(\text{the winner's first roll} = 5\mid \text{winner} = p)
\\={}&P(\text{the winner's first roll} = 5),
\end{align}
by the same independence reasoning as above; the working then continues as above.



Addendum




Solution 2 (which uses Bayes Theorem to correctly arrive at the answer)

Actually, Solution 2 is not less sketchy than Solution 1! Critically, all three instances of the string "Hugo wins on his/the next round" need to be changed to "Hugo subsequently wins".
Besides, Solution 2 should be clearer that its four cases are these conditional probabilities:

$P(\text{no player ties with Hugo in the first round},\; \text{winner} = \text{Hugo}\mid \text{Hugo's first roll} = 5)$
$P(\text{one player ties with Hugo in the first round},\; \text{winner} = \text{Hugo}\mid \text{Hugo's first roll} = 5)$
$P(\text{two players tie with Hugo in the first round},\; \text{winner} = \text{Hugo}\mid \text{Hugo's first roll} = 5)$
$P(\text{three players tie with Hugo in the first round},\; \text{winner} = \text{Hugo}\mid \text{Hugo's first roll} = 5)$

Summing these four probabilities gives $P(\text{winner} = \text{Hugo}\mid \text{Hugo's first roll} = 5);\tag*{}$ multiplying this by $\frac16$ gives $P(\text{Hugo's first roll} = 5,\;\text{winner} = \text{Hugo});\tag*{}$ dividing this by $\frac14$ finally gives $P(\text{Hugo's first roll} = 5\mid \text{winner} = \text{Hugo})\tag*{}$ (this is essentially Bayes' Theorem), as required.

Beautiful. The independence observation (for your first version), and the symmetry observation (for your second solution) are key to this problem.

I agree with the change in language required in Solution 2. Writing precisely is a very different skill from getting the correct answer in an objective exam.

@Starlight I’d chalk the error I pointed out as inaccuracy; on the other hand, it’s a judgement call whether it’s inaccurate or merely terse/imprecise that Solutions 1 & 2 continually refer to P(X|Y) as if it’s P(X).

Good points about both solutions. The level of checking that the reader has to do on each proof is far from trivial.

Just a note for the key independence part: if $A$ is the event in which the winner first rolls $5$, $B_k$ the event in which the $k$-th player wins, player $1$ is Hugo, then
$$P(A)=\sum_{1\leq k \leq 4}P(A\cap B_k)=4P(A\cap B_1)$$ (because no player is any different from another) so
$$P(A\cap B_1)=P(A)\cdot\frac{1}{4}=P(A)P(B_1)$$ which shows that $A,B_1$ are independent.

I am going to separate out the math into different lines (just makes it easier for me to understand). Not intending to change your answer/explanation in any way.

Symmetry arguments always need to be considered carefully, but the argument in this case is fairly strong.
Even more directly, let $W$ be the event that Hugo wins, $H_5$ the event that Hugo rolls a $5$ on the first roll, $R_5$ be the event that the highest roll on the first round is $5$.
Then $W \cap R_5 = W \cap R_5 \cap H_5 = W \cap H_5$. Therefore
$$ P(H_5 \mid W) = \frac{P(H_5 \cap W)}{P(W)}
 = \frac{P(R_5 \cap W)}{P(W)} = P(R_5 \mid W). $$
To link it specifically to "Solution 2", let $A$ be the event that on the first round, the high roll is a $5$. Moreover, let $F$ be the event that Hugo rolls a $5$ on the first roll, $W$ the event that Hugo wins. Separate the event $A$ into cases according to ties, similar to the cases in Solution 2.
Case 1: The first high roll is a $5$ and no players tie. That is, we have exactly one $5$ and three lower rolls. Call this event $A_1$. The single $5$ could be any of the four players. The unconditional probability of this event is
$$ P(A_1) = \dbinom41 \dfrac16\left(\dfrac46\right)^3 = \dfrac{16}{81}. $$
The probability this case occurs and Hugo is the one who rolled $5$ (and therefore Hugo wins) is
$$ P(A_1 \cap F) = \dfrac16\left(\dfrac46\right)^3 = \dfrac{4}{81}. $$
The probability that this case occurs and Hugo wins, given that Hugo rolled a $5$, is
$$ P(A_1 \cap W \mid F) = \dfrac{P(A_1 \cap W \cap F)}{P(F)}
 = \dfrac{P(A_1 \cap F)}{P(F)} = \dfrac{4/81}{1/6} = \dfrac8{27},$$
which is case 1 from Solution 2.
Case 2: The first high roll is a $5$ and two players tie. Call this event $A_2$.
$$ P(A_2) = \dbinom42 \left(\dfrac16\right)^2\left(\dfrac46\right)^2 = \dfrac{2}{27}. $$
The probability this case occurs and Hugo rolled $5$ is
$$ P(A_2 \cap F) = \dbinom31 \left(\dfrac16\right)^2\left(\dfrac46\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{27}. $$
But if Hugo rolled $5$, Hugo still has only $\frac12$ probability to win, so
$$ P(A_2 \cap W \mid F) = \dfrac{P(A_1 \cap W \cap F)}{P(F)}
 = \dfrac{\frac12 P(A_2 \cap F)}{P(F)} = \dfrac{\frac12\cdot 1/27}{1/6} = \dfrac19,$$
which is case 2 from Solution 2.
